# Pointer is not passed,printlist does not work

Tags: c, pointers, modularity

The printlist function in the following code does not work. When I pass a node pointer from the main function the value is not passed.

```
void printlist(node *head)
{

    node *current=head;

    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        printf("\n %d",current->data);
        current=current->next;
    }
}


int main(void)
{
    int ch=1;
    int choice=1;
    while(ch=1)
    {
        node *head;
        head=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("Press 1 for create list \n2 for display \n3 for add at end of list \n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);`


        switch(choice) {
        case 1:
            head=createlist();
            node *current=head;
            break;

        case 2:
            printf("Welcome to list printer");
            printlist(head);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

** Note:-create list works fine i have not put it here to reduce the question size,i have tried using the same print technique inside the main function and it has worked like a charm.Its only when I tried to implement it as a function that the error started.

Comment: Did you step through the code in a debugger or put in some printf statements in the code to examine values?  That would be the first thing to try.  Show all your code.

Comment: Are you sure your `createlist()` function works fine?

Comment: Notice that your while loop is broken, it probably should use ==

Comment: You also `malloc()` space for `head`, and then completely overwrite it and lose it when you call `createlist()`. That `node *current` under `case 1` is also going to be local to the `switch` block, and you don't use it. Also, don't cast the return from `malloc()`.

Comment: Actually, every time you go through that loop, you're losing the list you create. You want to move that `node *head` outside of the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your primary problem is here:

```
while(ch=1)
    {
        node *head;
```

`head` is local to the `while` block. After creating a new list on `case 1`, that variable will go out of scope and disappear before the loop comes round to give you a chance to print it. So you're just passing uninitialized memory to `printlist()`. You need:

```
node * head;
while (ch=1) {
```

There are numerous other problems with your code:

- `ch=1` means the while loop will never end, you don't seem to ever change `ch` anyway.
- you `malloc()` memory for `head`, but then overwrite the value of `head` when you call `createlist()` and lose that memory, without having ever used it.
- `node * current` is never used
- don't cast the return from `malloc()`

Comment: Paul,thanks for answering,The thing is this is only a fragment of the code and ch's value is changed in one of the cases that follow,the code works without the printlist function,if the printing is done inside the main function.

Comment: @Nahcraved: The issue with `ch` is the least of the problems. Like I said, the primary problem is the scope of `head`. In future, please make sure you post the actual code that you want an answer on. If you find yourself referring to other code you might have left out, then you run a serious risk of totally wasting the time of anyone who tries to help you. If you submit a code fragment, make sure that the code fragment compiles, and exhibits your problem in of and by itself. Nobody can help you with random code they can't see.

Comment: Sorry,paul.I am a new here,I promise this wont happen again.I will fix the scope and get back to you,many thanks.

Comment: I just exchanged the position of head,and the code worked .:)

Comment: Glad you got it figured out. Please accept the answer if it was what you needed.